# Autohotkey sending mail through ComObject

Tags: outlook, autohotkey, windows-task-scheduler, comobject

Problem:
I have made a script that sends a mail through ComObject and it works like a charm when i use it as user, but not if i execute it with Task Scheduler.

---

What have i done? I have changed ComObjActive to ComObjCreate.

---

Code:

The body is correct and contains HTML text.

```
Myself = %AUMailAdress%
Recipient := Myself
Subject := Oi
Body := Ci
Recipient5 = Hidden@gmail.com

DocumentLocation = %SourceDir%\Tooloutput\AutoProjectsLog\Faults



olMailItem := 0
MailItem := ComObjCreate("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(olMailItem)
olFormatHTML := 2
MailItem.BodyFormat := olFormatHTML
MailItem.Subject := Subject
MailItem.HTMLBody := Body
Recipient := MailItem.Recipients.Add(Recipient)
Recipient.Type := 1 
Loop, %DocumentLocation%\*.*
MailItem.Attachments.Add(A_LoopFileLongPath)
MailItem.cc := Recipient5
MailItem.Send

  

ExitApp 
return
```

---

Issue:
The following error i get when it tries to make a ComObject.

> Error: 0x80080005 - Server execution failed
>
> Line: #
>
> ---> 674: MailItem: = ComObjCreate ("Outlook.Application"). CreateItem (olMailItem)

Continuous running the script?

Comment: In Task Scheduler, have you tried setting "Run only when user is logged on" and "Run with highest privileges", and then use your user account to run as?

Comment: The option "Run only when user is logged on" is not good enough, because the script has to run in the night. "Run with highest privileges" is already toggled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just struggled with this about 3 hours, trying many things, including this method:

[MSDN Method | ",512"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/870655/you-may-receive-an-error-code-80080005-server-execution-failed-error-m)

At the end, I just ran Outlook as administrator and all started working properly, using this code:

```
outlookApp := ComObjCreate("Outlook.Application")
MailItem := outlookApp.CreateItem(0)
MailItem.Display
```

System: Windows 10 x64

Outlook 2019

AHK 1.1.33.02 ran as administrator